# Responsive div - text wrapping div. Can this be stacked when minimized?

Tags: css, html, css-float, media, right-align

I have set up a global element to align images to the right:

```
.containerright {
    float: right; margin: 5px 5px 5px 10px; position:relative;
}
```

It works perfectly until the screen is minimized to mobile portrait size. Then the text wrap leaves a few words behind.

For example:

```
<div class="containerright"><img src="/images/imageexample.jpg" width="223" height="160" hspace="0" vspace="5" alt="imageexample" border="0"></div>

<h2>Here is an example of heading text!</h2>
```

When minimised 'Here is an example...' is aligned to the top-left of the image and the rest of the sentence '...of heading text!' falls under the image so there is a huge break where the image is sitting to its right.

How can I set the class so that when it's viewed '@media (max-width: 320px)' it stacks eg. display:block; ???

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove the float in the media query CSS. :)

```
@media (max-width: 320px) {
.containerright {
    float: right; /* remove the float on the mobile media query */
    margin: 5px 5px 5px 10px; 
    position:relative;
}
}
```

[**jsFiddle example here**](http://jsfiddle.net/7WmWK/).. resize the screen to see what it would look like on a mobile < 320px.

Alternatively, you could just override it in the media query..

```
@media (max-width: 320px) {
.containerright {
    float:none;
}
}
```

Comment: Wow that was so quick! Thanks, I'll give it a try now. :)

Comment: @user2744820 let me know if it worked.. if you have any more questions let me know :)

Comment: Woo hoo! This worked. Thanks!!

    @media screen and (max-width:320px) {
 .containerright {
 float: none;
 }
}

Comment: @media screen and (max-width:320px) {
 .containerright {
 float: none;
 }
}

Comment: But obviously only on a screen. I still have the issue when minimising a browser, but that's not an issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
@media (max-width: 320px) {
  .containerright {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

Comment: Add some explanation.